# How to make images position properly on lower resolutions without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make website which has some icons on map. The problem is, that when I am making window smaller icons have wrong position, and they are in different places than I would like them to be. Also I cannot use bootstrap to position them. Only HTML, CSS and JS/jQuery.

Option 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snh4C.jpg
Option 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrvcf.jpg

I have already tried thing like:

```
   min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 body .background .foodini-logo img{
        width:15%;
        height:15%;
        margin-top: 10%
        margin-left:12%;
   }
 }
```

It only changed it for a while, because with resolution getting lower I had to add another media like every 100px, which is not an option for every icon I think.

```
html{
   height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background: url("../img/bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:rgb(178,212,238);

}
.
.
.
body .background .foodini-logo{
        margin-top:15%;
        margin-left:17%;

}
body .background .haps-logo {
        margin-top: 35%;
        margin-left: 23%;
}
```

I would like to have this icons be all the time as in option 1, no matter what resolution user will have on his screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is that you're trying to use `background-size: cover` with `position: relative` logos. Cover is going to grow and shrink based on how large the elements are inside it. But you don't want that.

```
.background {
    background: url("../img/bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: rgb(178,212,238);
    padding-bottom: 65%;
}
```

Changing the background-size to `100% auto` will make the background 100% wide without stretching. I also added `padding` to make sure the container will keep the correct height ratio, since we're going to make the logo `position: absolute` so they don't conflict with each other.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.haps-logo {
    top: 35%;
    left: 23%;
}
```

I added `transform` so the logos are centered on their position, rather than being pinned to the top-left of the logo. A bit easier in my opinion, but not required.

If you post a codepen or jsfiddle link with your code we can make sure it works, but otherwise, you can adapt this to your current setup.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I solved my problem with some JS code: 
```
unction doResize(event, ui) {

    var scale, origin;

    scale = Math.min(
        ui.size.width / elWidth,
        ui.size.height / elHeight
    );

    $el.css({
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%) " + "scale(" + scale + ")"
    });

}
```
but it's not perfect. I'll try your example for sure. Thank you very much for your help.